# Mappings : use CopyTo from a nested object to feed a parent property

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have these classes :

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<B> Children { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> SearchField { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I work on an application that requires to copy into the property "SearchField" all the data that can be searched. I'm trying to copy in this field the value of the Name property of all the B children, but for the moment I didn't find a way to do that...

Any idea ? My current code :

```
map
    .Properties(props => props
        .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.SearchField))
        .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Name))
        .Object<B>(c => c
            .Name(n => n.Children)
            .Properties(p => p
                .Text(t => t.Name(b => b.Name)).CopyTo(a => ???????)
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping and explain in mapping which properties your are trying to copy to `SearchField` property?

Comment: Here is an answer to my similar question from Russ Cam. Seems like the missing piece for you is 'Infer.Field' https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014792/5569485

Comment: Old question here... I just tested the solution from Russ Cam, it's working perfectly. @EricPhillips : post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @schglurps You can post the answer yourself and link back to the other answer,  as I don't know the exact way it would work with IEnumerable properties. Better to have a precise solution for future searchers than getting a few points :)