# Copying a nested property to parent object in elasticsearch with Nest client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I copy a nested property into a field of the containing POCO in an index mapping definition?

I am able to successfully copy a property into another property with `.CopyTo` *when both fields are at the same object level.*

However I am struggling with copying a property on a nested object into a property on the parent object.

Given the objects below, I would like to copy 'Street' from the Address property on a Person into the 'Search' property on Person

```cs
Person
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

Address 
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping 'LastName' into 'Search' is simple, as below.

```cs
.Map<Person>(map => map
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(properties => properties
                .Text(text => 
                    text.Name(name => name.LastName)
                        .CopyTo(copyTo => 
                            copyTo.Field(field => field.Search)
                        )
                    )
                )
```

However I cannot figure out the Nest syntax to copy 
'Person.Address.Street' into 'Person.Search'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "my_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Person>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Object<Address>(o => o
                        .Name(n => n.Address)
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Properties(pp => pp
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(nn => nn.Street)
                                .CopyTo(co => co
                                    .Field(Infer.Field<Person>(ff => ff.Search))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var indexResponse = client.Index(new Person
        {
            LastName = "foo",
            Address = new Address
            {
                Street = "bar"
            }
        } , i => i
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Match(m => m
                .Field(f => f.Search)
                .Query("bar")
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Person
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially

1. Automap the `Person` properties
2. Explicitly map the `Address` property on `Person`
3. Automap the `Address` properties
4. Explicitly map the `Street` property and set up `CopyTo(...)`. At this point, the generic type parameter is the `Address` type, so you either need to use `Nest.Infer.Field<T>` to access the `Search` property of `Person`, or use a string.

The search returns the expected document

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "person",
        "_id" : "5tQDEWgBrKRHlz9qAve8",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "lastName" : "foo",
          "address" : {
            "street" : "bar"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`copy_to` fields in Elasticsearch don't necessarily need to be exposed as a property on the C# POCO, since the `_source` won't contain a value for them. Exposing as a property however may be useful for strong typing field access.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the quick reply.  You are a magician

Comment: Absolutely wonderful, thank you!